R st_intersects gives out sgbp file
Basically I have a data frame with coordinates variables and other variables, and another SHP file provides polygones geographic information:
I want to find out which points are inside these polygones and get their polygones' names.
So I transfer data frame to sf by using st_as_sf, and st_read to import the polygone file. Then I use st_intersects to intersect these two sf file and that gives me a "Large sgbp" file in R. I'm confused.(I do not use st_intersections because that's too slow and my database is very big.)
Could sb points out where is the problem or any other way to do that?
By the way I tried st_join and that works well and I get a sf file then I can transfer it back to data frame to continue other works.

st_intersects() returns either dense logical matrix either sparse list (your sgbp object). If your request is to have polygons names assigned to your poitns then yes, st_join is a way to go, otherwise sf::st_filter() is the way to filter out the points inside polygon.

Does st_join have a duplicate problem for the points fell on the border line?

st_join() has a join argument where you can define predicate, like sf::st_join(..., join = st_within). See help for st_join()

make sense thank you

sf::st_intersects() returning an object of class sgbp (=sparse geometry binary predicate list) per default (with sparse = TRUE) is desired behaviour. The result is a list containing the object indices for which the chosen predicate (here: intersects) applies.
Let me show you making use of the nc dataset that comes with {sf} with 500 random points distributed across the area where we want to know which points fall inside a certain polygon:
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.8.2, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))
#> Reading layer `nc' from data source `shape\nc.shp' 
#>   using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27

set.seed(42)
p <- st_sample(nc, 500)

# inspect
plot(st_geometry(nc))
plot(p, add = TRUE)

# highlight some random polygon
nc_sub <- nc[1, ]

plot(st_geometry(nc_sub), border = "red", add = TRUE)
plot(p[nc_sub, ], col = "red", pch = 20, add = TRUE)


Now we can determine which points are inside our polygon in several different ways. As illustrated, our expectation is to identify four points:
# Option 1: returns sgbp, which can be used for further indexing
ind <- sf::st_intersects(nc_sub, p)
ind
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 1, where the predicate
#> was `intersects'
#>  1: 87, 277, 338, 362

p[ind[[1]], ]
#> Geometry set for 4 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.68241 ymin: 36.32215 xmax: -81.48794 ymax: 36.57989
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> POINT (-81.51258 36.32215)
#> POINT (-81.48794 36.37173)
#> POINT (-81.55579 36.57989)
#> POINT (-81.68241 36.52545)

# Option 2: returns simple features
sf::st_intersection(nc_sub, p)
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.68241 ymin: 36.32215 xmax: -81.48794 ymax: 36.57989
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#>      AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1   0.114     1.442  1825    1825 Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 1.1 0.114     1.442  1825    1825 Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 1.2 0.114     1.442  1825    1825 Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 1.3 0.114     1.442  1825    1825 Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#>     NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                   geometry
#> 1        10  1364     0      19 POINT (-81.51258 36.32215)
#> 1.1      10  1364     0      19 POINT (-81.48794 36.37173)
#> 1.2      10  1364     0      19 POINT (-81.55579 36.57989)
#> 1.3      10  1364     0      19 POINT (-81.68241 36.52545)

# Option 3: spatial indexing
p[nc_sub, ]
#> Geometry set for 4 features 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.68241 ymin: 36.32215 xmax: -81.48794 ymax: 36.57989
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> POINT (-81.51258 36.32215)
#> POINT (-81.48794 36.37173)
#> POINT (-81.55579 36.57989)
#> POINT (-81.68241 36.52545)

With the subset of your points returned, you should be able to proceed with whatever operation you like, e.g. getting their names, if these are present in some column.

Yes that makes sense, but st_intersection is too long too rolling I may find st_join does faster

@user24010620: st_intersection() is the slowest from the above, yes. You might also be able to use st_join() with join = st_intersects but pay attention to the different output.
st_join(st_as_sf(p), nc_sub) gives you POINT geometry for all 500 objects with all attributes being NA except for the four relevant points, and st_join(nc_sub, st_as_sf(p)) gives you MULTIPOLYGON geometry, identifying (and replicating) the polygon intersecting with the points, losing the geometry information of the intersecting points. This totally depends on your actual needs which method to choose.
